# ServiceStack OrmLite wrong SQL?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have the following class:

```
    public class ProcessInstance
    {
        [AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Reference]
        public ProcessDefinition ProcessDefinition { get; set; }
        public int ProcessDefinitionId { get; set; }

        // and more...
}
```

Then running the following, which looks fine to me:

```
var q = db.From<ProcessInstance>().Where(inst => inst.ProcessDefinition.Id == id
                && Sql.In(inst.Status, enProcessStatus.READY, enProcessStatus.ACTIVE));
return db.Exists(q);
```

When I inspect the last command text SQL from the "db" object, it's wrong:

```
SELECT 'exists' 
FROM "ProcessInstance"
WHERE (("Id" = @0) AND "Status" IN (@1,@2))
LIMIT 1
```

Note that it's filtering on `Id` instead of `ProcessDefinition.Id`, which of course is wrong. Don't know why it's doing that -- at least I'd appreciate getting an error instead of just a wrong result.

However, I've found how to fix it: Use ProcessDefinitionId: `Where(inst => inst.ProcessDefinitionId == id` gives the correct SLQ:

```
SELECT 'exists' 
FROM "ProcessInstance"
WHERE (("ProcessDefinitionId" = @0) AND "Status" IN (@1,@2))
LIMIT 1
```

Why didn't the first one work? Why is there no error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OrmLite is designed for providing a typed api around an SQL Expression so that it should be intuitive to determine the SQL generated from a typed Expression. It doesn’t support magic behavior such as querying any nested objects as attempted with the reference complex type property, I.e. you can only query direct column properties as done in your 2nd query.

Comment: It is perfectly OK that there are limitations, but that it just made another query (queried for another field) was not that nice, and of course leads to bugs. Of course one can make the argument that this is human error, wrong use etc., and I don't disagree, but still, an exception instead of making a different SQL would be nice. Maybe a future improvement.